# Sort fltered table data

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sorting, autofilter

I have this code within a loop that sets autofilter to a dynamically generated table and shows only a few rows out of many based on the filters used. The autofilter within the loop works perfect, but what I need is to sort it alphabetically (A to Z) based on the Values that came out.

My problem is that I can't manage to find a way to select the range of shown data in column A and filter it Alphabetically. Can someone help me out here? I will add a picture of what I mean :D

[table_filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h525i.png)

[[table_select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjXye.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW2HY.png)

[table_sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM4bH.png)

Thank you guys in advance

I tried selecting the range with last cell with a value and other selection ways, but I couldn't manage to create a generic way in order to use it within a loop.

I can't find a way to grab the visible data in column A of that table and use it as a range to sort the data from a to Z

Update: I attached the code where I would like to sort the data.

So before this code is used I have a very long table with up to 64000 entries. I filter the table based on multiple criteria within an array in order to get 5 to 7 names filtered on a specific date. which you can see here:

```
    Sheets("5.0").Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=ID_range
    Sheets("5.0").Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=FQ_Date
```

After this filter is applied I would like the result to be sorted from A to Z in order to grab that sorted info as you can see in the pictures above and paste it at the destination sheet.

```
Sub filter_with_array_as_criteria_FQ()

Dim FQ_Range As String
Dim FQ_Date As String
Dim FQ_Output_50 As String

For rep = Range("O6").Value To Range("P6").Value

    FQ_Range = Sheets("Admin").Range("J" & rep).Value
    FQ_Date = Sheets("Admin").Range("M" & rep).Value
    FQ_Output_50 = Sheets("Admin").Range("K" & rep).Value
    FQ_Output_24 = Sheets("Admin").Range("L" & rep).Value


    Dim ID_range, k As Variant
    ID_range = Application.Transpose(Sheets("KW_Bericht_Report").Range(FQ_Range))

    For k = LBound(ID_range) To UBound(ID_range)
    ID_range(k) = CStr(ID_range(k))
    Next k
    Sheets("5.0").Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=ID_range
    Sheets("5.0").Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=FQ_Date
    'Hier muss Tabelle sortiert werden/ This is where the filtered Data needs to be sorted
    
    
    
    'Select values from listobject column 4 paste on kwbericht
    Sheets("5.0").Select
    Sheets("5.0").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Sheets("KW_Bericht_Report").Range(FQ_Output_50).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    'Select Sheet 2.4
    Sheets("2.4").Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=ID_range
    Sheets("2.4").Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=FQ_Date
    'Hier muss Tabelle sortiert werden/ This is where the filtered Data needs to be sorted
    
    
    'Select values from listobject column 4 paste on kwbericht
    Sheets("2.4").Select
    Sheets("2.4").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Sheets("KW_Bericht_Report").Range(FQ_Output_24).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    
    Debug.Print (FQ_Date)
    Debug.Print (FQ_Range)
Next rep
    Sheets("KW_Bericht_Report").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What does *"based on the Values that came out"* mean? All your screenshots show the same. What's wrong with sorting the range before applying the filter? Please share the code that you're using and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Please post your current code, including what you tried to apply the sorting.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I added the code with some commentaries to it. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim thanks for taking your time with this! I added the code with some comments.

Comment: Why not sort the whole table first, as suggested?  Then your filtered data will not need to be sorted.  Your filtered data may not be a contiguous range (ie. will have multiple areas) so you will not be able to sort that.

Comment: @TimWilliams i would love to try that out, I don’t know how to address the table and range once it is created. How would you sort the table first before applying the filter?

Comment: Previously here:  https://www.google.com/search?q=VBA+sort+listobject+site:stackoverflow.com